# Симпатяшка, денежка, крутышка - Ж или Ш надо писать?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать и какие объяснения у вышеуказанных слов?

Answer (score 3):

1) Симпатичный – симпат/яг/а, но:  **симпатичный – симпат/яшк/а.** Суффикс ЯШК, усечение основы. Написание соответствует орфографическому словарю под редакцией Лопатина.

Симпатяшка https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/375270/

2) **Деньги – денеж/к/а,** чередование Г/Ж.

3) **Крутой – крут/ышк/а** (из молодежного сленга). Суффикс ЫШК.

http://teenslang.su/id/715

**Комментарий**

Симпатяшка – относительно новая форма письма, многие пользователи считают, что правильно: симпатичный – симпатяга – симпатяжка, чередование Г/Ж.

Например: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1055046-kak-pravilno--simpatjashka-ili-simpatjazhka.html

И вывод (для себя): надо чаще заглядывать в новый орфографический словарь, даже если  уверен в написании слова.

Общие положения к теме:

1) **Ж пишется только в суффиксе ЁЖК/ЕЖК**, который используется при образовании существительного от глагола: кормить – кормёжка, сладко есть  – сладкоежка.
**Также возможно сочетание Ж в корне (с учетом чередования) + суффикс К**: фляга – фляжка, бедняга – бедняжка, дворняга – дворняжка, строгать – стружка, семга – сёмужка.

**В остальных суффиксах  (УШК/ЮШК, ЯШК, ИШК) пишется Ш**:  девочка – девчушка, парень – парнишка – суффиксы субъективной оценки УШК, ИШК,  Б) дерево – деревяшка, медь – медяшка, болтать – болтушка,  голый – голышка, копчёный – копчушка – словообразовательные суффиксы.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке нет суффиксов **-ижк**, **-ыжк**, **-ужк**, **-южк** (upd. это не совсем верно, см. в ответе **Sharon** про отглагольные существительные), все только через **ш**. Сочетание букв **жка** появляется в результате чередования **г — ж**. Например: бумага — бумажка, деньга — денежка, пробег — пробежка, Олег — Олежка и т.п.

В некоторых случаях словообразование может быть неочевидным. Например, торопыга — торопыжка, но коротышка образовано не от слова "коротыга" (такого слова нет). Поэтому, даже выдумывая несуществующее в языке слово (например, указанное Вами **крутышка**), нужно понимать, от какого слова оно образовано. И если Вы хотите образовать его от существующего слова "крутой", это будет меньшим злом, чем образование от другого несуществующего слова "крутыга". Поэтому лучше написать **крутышка**, чем крутыжка.

А **симпатяжка** можно образовать и от законного слова "симпатяга", и такое слово есть в Викисловаре. Хотя в академическом словаре Лопатина **симпатяшка**.

Answer (score 0):

Помимо академических справочников, могут помочь аналогично устроенные слова с очевидным написанием:

серьга - сережка, деньга - денежка

бродяга - бродяжка, симпатяга - симпатяжка

пустая - пустышка, крутая - крутышка